# Use of deb in Singular installation

Tags: deb

Just switched to ubuntu 14. I tried to install Singular (CA system) without success. Here the owner manual

Step-by-step instructions for Ubuntu 14.04:

- Add gpg key:

  - `wget ftp://jim.mathematik.uni-kl.de/repo/extra/gpg`
  - `apt-key add gpg`
- Add `deb ftp://jim.mathematik.uni-kl.de/repo/ubuntu14 trusty main` to `/etc/apt/sources.list`
- `apt-get update`
- `apt-get install singular`

Here what I did so far:

```
 ~$ wget ftp://jim.mathematik.uni-kl.de/repo/extra/gpg
 ~$ sudo apt-key add gpg    
 ~$ deb ftp://jim.mathematik.uni-kl.de/repo/ubuntu14 trusty main
  ~> No command 'deb' found...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The step-by-step instructions for Ubuntu 14.04 said to open the sources.list file located at `/etc/apt/sources.list` for editing. You can open the sources.list file for editing in nano text editor using this command:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add this line to sources.list:

```
deb ftp://jim.mathematik.uni-kl.de/repo/ubuntu14 trusty main
```

Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the changes in sources.list.

Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.

Then run these two commands to update the latest list of software and then install singular:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install singular
```

If you get this error when trying to use `apt-get`:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11 Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

...the instructions for fixing it are at this question:
[Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your effort, as with the method above I get after the sudo apt-get update command the following:<br> E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open<br> (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)<br> E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/

Comment: <br> obviously are linebreaks

Answer (score 0):

The instructions said to **open** the `sources.list` file located at `/etc/apt` folder and **append** to it the `deb ftp://jim.mathematik.uni-kl.de/repo/ubuntu14 trusty main` line.

The easiest procedure is to replace this step with this command that does it for you:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb ftp://jim.mathematik.uni-kl.de/repo/ubuntu14 trusty main"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your effort, as with the method below I get after the sudo apt-get update command the following:<br> E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open<br> (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)<br> E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/

Comment: <br> obviously are linebreaks

Comment: Are you running any update/installation process at the same time?

Comment: @J.M.P. Did rou ran it as root?